# How to give write permission to everybody?

Tags: c, unix, permissions, system-calls, umask

After the following code runs, file *tasty* has permission bits set to `0700`, which is unexpected.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fild = creat("tasty", 0722);
    close(fild);
    return 0;
}
```

How to allow everybody to write into the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shell probably has a umask of `022`, which means any new files created will have the specified bits (i.e. group write and other write) cleared.

You need to set the umask to 0 before creating the file:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
    umask(0);
    int fild = creat("tasty", 0722);
    close(fild);
    return 0;
}
```